# Can it be mathematically proven that a block can be solved?

Tags: block, nonce

In other words, that there exists a nonce for the block that will result in sha256(sha256(block header + nonce)) hash under the current difficulty barrier number.

Comment: It would be better, if we could relate block n, in terms of f(block n-1).

Comment: I agree with some of the comments in the answers that this question is poorly worded. I'm going to submit an edit to what I think he means "how do we know that a block as a valid answer?", but that will essentially be a dup of "http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/is-it-possible-for-the-network-to-stop-finding-valid-blocks" so I will submit a dup close as well.

Comment: On second thought, this might not be a true duplicate, so I'll just post an answer that covers the gaps between this question (at least with my pending edits) and that one.

Answer (score 4):

The clients make use of the [Target](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Target) to determine if a block hash is valid and will be accepted by the network. The Bitcoin wiki states the following:

> The target is a 256-bit number (extremely large) that all Bitcoin
> clients share. The SHA-256 hash of a block's header must be lower than
> or equal to the current target for the block to be accepted by the
> network. The lower the target, the more difficult it is to generate a
> block. [...]
>
> Each hash basically gives you a random number between 0 and the
> maximum value of a 256-bit number (which is huge). If your hash is
> below the target, then you win. If not, you increment the nonce
> (completely changing the hash) and try again.

The current target value can be found here: http://blockexplorer.com/q/hextarget

Comment: Well, I am asking for mathematical formula that determines the existence of N valid blocks. That miners can find.

Comment: Then ask a question in understandable English.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way of proving that a hash exists other than actually finding that hash. (i.e. brute force). The existence of a method of being able to predict the result of a hash other than computing the hash would render the hash function cryptographically unsound. (And so we can infer that no mathematician has found such a method for SHA-256).

That said, as discussed [in this other Q&A](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/is-it-possible-for-the-network-to-stop-finding-valid-blocks), there are a number of characteristics of a block that are dynamic so it isn't as if an "insolvable" block would actually cause any network problems.

Comment: do it implies? If sha256 has a unknown flaw, with non "random" data, block can not be solved with current "difficulty"?
number of nonces per "diff space" vs expected probability results?

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't understand your English. But I think what you are asking is answered in the other question I linked to. Remember that a block isn't particularly "fixed". The coin base, the transactions, the order of the transactions, the timestamp: these all can change. Even if you could craft a block that is insolvable by using an unknown vulnerability in SHA-256 (and that's a huge if), changing any of those other inputs would result in a different (solvable) block.